# TensorFlow On Spark: Can't pickle local object loop

Tags: apache-spark, tensorflow, parallel-processing, pyspark, pickle

I have a Standalone Spark Cluster and try to run [TensorFlow On Spark](https://github.com/yahoo/TensorFlowOnSpark/wiki) on it using Python. So far, I have just tried very simple examples but I always run into the same problem: Every worker crashes with the same error message:

```
AttributeError: Can't pickle local object 'start.<locals>.<lambda>'
```

A new worker is assigned and I am ultimately stuck in an infinite `Waiting for reservations...` loop. There is no explicit pickling in my program so I guess it must be part of the TensorFlow On Spark pipeline. Without the Spark wrapper my TensorFlow applications run fine. I have tested this both on Windows 7 and CentOS Linux 7 with the same behavior.

The (almost) full error output is the following:

```
17/08/15 16:40:36 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.2 in stage 0.0 (TID 5)
org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Spark\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\worker.py", line 177, in main
  File "D:\Spark\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\worker.py", line 172, in process
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyspark\rdd.py", line 2423, in pipeline_func
    return func(split, prev_func(split, iterator))
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyspark\rdd.py", line 2423, in pipeline_func
    return func(split, prev_func(split, iterator))
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyspark\rdd.py", line 2423, in pipeline_func
    return func(split, prev_func(split, iterator))
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyspark\rdd.py", line 346, in func
    return f(iterator)
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyspark\rdd.py", line 794, in func
    r = f(it)
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflowonspark\TFSparkNode.py", line 290, in _mapfn
    TFSparkNode.mgr = TFManager.start(authkey, ['control'], 'remote')
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflowonspark\TFManager.py", line 41, in start
    mgr.start()
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\managers.py", line 513, in start
    self._process.start()
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 105, in start
    self._popen = self._Popen(self)
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 322, in _Popen
    return Popen(process_obj)
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\popen_spawn_win32.py", line 65, in __init__
    reduction.dump(process_obj, to_child)
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\reduction.py", line 60, in dump
    ForkingPickler(file, protocol).dump(obj)
AttributeError: Can't pickle local object 'start.<locals>.<lambda>'
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonRDD.scala:193)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.<init>(PythonRDD.scala:234)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner.compute(PythonRDD.scala:152)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:63)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:335)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 105, in spawn_main
    exitcode = _main(fd)
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 115, in _main
    self = reduction.pickle.load(from_parent)
```

It seems like this issue is [known](https://github.com/yahoo/TensorFlowOnSpark/issues/36), but no solution exists. Any hint would be appreciated since I am out of ideas.